# Active record table_exists? syntax

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord

How can I get the following code to work? I can't find syntax that works for me.

```
#Create the table
if table_exists?(tablename)
puts "table found"
else
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
create_table :data do |table|
    table.column :date, :string
    table.column :word, :string
    table.column :website, :string
end
puts "table created"
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some alternatives:

```
# Ask from the DB connection
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists?(:xyz)

# Query tables from Schema
ActiveRecord::Schema.tables.include?("xyz")

# Xyz is your model class, check if its table is present
Xyz.table_exists?
```